# Why can't I see my HTML content in my App?

Tags: facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I'm new to developing for Facebook. I'm trying to create a "Welcome" tab, and I'm unable to see content after adding the App to my Page. I'm a little confused on Canvas Page URL and Page Tab URL. Should they be the same URL minus the HTML filename?

Answer (score 0):

The canvas page url is the folder where the page is stored:

ex. http://www.myurl.com/facebooktabs/

the Page tab url is the exact url of the content:

ex. http://www.myurl.com/facebooktabs/index.php

make sure you give the secure page tab url an address as well:

ex. https://www.myurl.com/facebooktabs/index.php

Comment: I noticed that your example is .php. Would a .html file not work?